# How to receive update activity transition using ActivityRecognitionClient in android Oreo?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, activity-recognition

I used ActivityRecognitionClient to request update activity transition and receive result in pending intent broadcast receiver. But my broadcast receiver never trigger. It works well on android 7 Nougat, but not work on android 8 Oreo. I know there are some limits for background execution in android 8, but i don't know ActivityRecognitionClient is affected. Someone has experience on this please give me some ideas to solve this problem. Thanks so much.